# Why does 冬休みは家族でイタリアやイギリスへ行きました。 have で instead of と?

Tags: particle-と, particle-で

Why does this sentence:

> 冬休みは家族でイタリアやイギリスへ行きました。

have `で` there instead of `と`?

Wouldn't "with family" be `家族と`?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

家族で should be taken as "as a family" rather than "with family"

(Both と and で could be used, though IMHO, 家族で implies that all family members were present whereas 家族と implies you only went with some/maybe all family members.)

Answer (score 7):

Both 家族で and 家族と are correct.

で can sometimes mark an organization/group which makes some action, as if it were a subject.

It's the third definition [on デジタル大辞泉](http://dictionary.goo.ne.jp/jn/148951/meaning/m0u/%E3%81%A7/).

> 動作・作用を行う主体となる組織・団体を表す。「政府側―検討中だ」「気象庁―光化学スモッグ警報を発令した」

[東京外国語大学言語モジュール](http://www.coelang.tufs.ac.jp/mt/ja/gmod/courses/c01/lesson14/step2/explanation/053.html) treats this as an extension of で as a location marker, as follows:

> 10　場所を表わす用法の拡張として、主語を場所風に表わすときに用いることがあります。
>
> - 警察**で**事件を調べています。
> - クラス**で**旅行に出かけました。
> - その仕事は自分**で**やります。

This question is also related:

- [で　used for abstract location?](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/2494/5010)

I think it's also possible to think of this as an extension of 1人で, みんなで, 全員で, etc.