# what does the particle で do in this sentence

Tags: particle-で

Can anyone here please help me with this sentence?
私達は交代で運転した, what does で mean here?

Comment: Possible duplicate: https://japanese.stackexchange.com/a/57177/9831 / https://japanese.stackexchange.com/a/2496/9831

Comment: Does this answer your question? [can someone explain the use で in this sentence: 今日も元気で過ごせたらイイよね](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/57172/can-someone-explain-the-use-%e3%81%a7-in-this-sentence-%e4%bb%8a%e6%97%a5%e3%82%82%e5%85%83%e6%b0%97%e3%81%a7%e9%81%8e%e3%81%94%e3%81%9b%e3%81%9f%e3%82%89%e3%82%a4%e3%82%a4%e3%82%88%e3%81%ad)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One of the basic functions of the case particle で is to mark the means
of an action.

Literally the sentence then means "We drove by alternation", which in human English will be "We drove there by taking turns behind the wheel".

Comment: @Nster This answer is not correct, I'm afraid.

Comment: @Chocolate how so? Please elaborate.